# benchmark Result for MovieLens dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, recommender-system

I am looking for a benchmark result or any kaggle competition held using MovieLens(20M or latest) dataset.

Similar question has been asked [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/bechmark-for-movielens) but, provided links are dead so re-raising the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One result for MovieLens 20M using Factorization Machine can be found [here](https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hivemall-movielens20m-fm). They got MAE: 0.60 and RMSE: 0.80.

Another result for MovieLens 20M using Autoencoders can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.07659.pdf). They got RMSE: 0.81.

Comment: the first link doesn't exist